# LibGDX -class TagGame contains a signature 'LArrayList<>;' ill-formed at position 11

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have no idea what's wrong. The error came up after I tried to use an ArrayList to store `Player` types. I've since erased everything I did, which was only three lines, but the error won't go away.
I tried restarting Eclipse, cleaning/rebuilding, and refreshing. Still there. The only thing I haven't done is move all the code to a brand-new project, but that's a huge pain in the butt so I'd like to avoid that. And I would like to know what causes this error so as to avoid it in the future.
This is how I used the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Player> players;
...
public void create() {
    players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    players.add(p1);
    players.add(p2);
}
```

This has worked in other applications, so I don't see why it should be different with LibGDX. Or why the error won't go away after erasing everything to do with it.

Edit: the error occurs on the letter "p" of "package" in the `DesktopLauncher` class. The ArrayList is in the main Game class.

Edit 2: if I try to run it, the console outputs `Error: Could not find or load main class com.fun.tag.desktop.DesktopLauncher`. The file exists, for sure, and could be opened before the error came up - literally nothing changed in the project other than four small lines. Those lines were never even compiled.

Comment: Above code is in your game class, but not in your DesktopLauncher class, is that correct ? Do you have any compilation error in your game class ?

Comment: No, not in the game class.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post so it's likely you've resolved this already but for anyone else that finds this with the same question here is what I did to fix it.

**Fix**

1) Back up your files. Not just for safety, we're gonna use it in a bit.

2) Anywhere you used an Array List remove that code.

3) Save those.

3) Now where you have the error get rid of the line (the line should be your package at the start of your class), now your error will read something like this:

> The declared package "" does not match the expected package...

4) Put back the line you just got rid of. (I did it bit by bit and running the program every time I added some just to be safe and to see if there was a specific line causing the error but it didn't seem to so you should be fine adding it all back at once)

5) Errors should be gone

6) Now any file that you took the code of out earlier you can put back from your backup.

**Why**

From what I have read and seen this is an error with the Eclipse IDE and not your code. I think the reason this may work, correct me if I am wrong, is that getting rid of the line that has the error on it will make it go away and when putting it back, since there is no actual error in your code causing this, the error will not reappear. Then you're able to add the code back since the error is not there and it should stay that way since, once again, there shouldn't be an actual issue with your code.

As for what causes this issue in the first place I am unsure to but if anyone has an answer to that I would be interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 3):

I was just having the same issue. What fixed it for me is this:

1. Remove the Project from Eclipse (don't delete the files of course).
2. Delete the .project-file and bin-directory. (Keep the .classpath-file)
3. Create a new project in the project directory.

I assume this is a bug in Eclipse, but I don't know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through this issue, and i really got scared by the "remove project then use backup" from the other answer so i really just deleted the package line in my Main class, which was the line that was showing the issue, then pressed ctrl+z to put the line back. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just does the maven clean for entire project and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve for me, was to copy the source code from each class showing the error, to a notepad.
Then I created the classes again and pasted the same code.
Finally I did all the imports and worked perfectly.